# Python Pandas combining 2 data frames by joining value to column name

Tags: python, pandas

If I have this dataframe `df1`:

```
       ABC    DEF    XYZ
1      9      4      1
2      4      6      9
3      7      9      8
4      6      3      8
5      1      2      3
```

And this dataframe `df2`:

```
       Name
1      ABC
2      DEF
3      ABC
4      XYZ
5      ABC
```

How do I get a dataframe like the below?

```
       Name Value
1       ABC     9
2       DEF     6
3       ABC     7
4       XYZ     8
5       ABC     1
```

Comment: You're right. It's a typo

Comment: I think it is a typo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) here:

```
df2['Value']=df1.lookup(df2.Name.index,df2.Name.values)
print(df2)
```

---

```
  Name  Value
1  ABC      9
2  DEF      6
3  ABC      7
4  XYZ      8
5  ABC      1
```